# How to configure base url for subdomain on DigitalOcean VPS?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, digital-ocean

The code is working when in `example.com`, but when used in `subdomain.example.com` it only shows a blank page. The subdomain is hosted on a different VPS server rather when changed code with the absolute path, rather than `{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}` to `subdomain.example.com` css, js works, but database connectivity is not establishing. Tried all methods nothing seems to work and it is worked in cpanel before, but not working in separate VPS in DigitalOcean.

```
$config['base_url'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https' : 'http') . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the base_url dynamically? check this than

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

Comment: I think the code works fine but the problem is with the VPS server is not getting subdomain.example.com as HTTP host properly but when used example.com it works

Comment: i tested the same thing on vps server and i am not getting any problem. check what URL you are getting from your side.

Comment: Could I get your email id so would ping you, in it.

Comment: curtnaithen@gmail.com